# Spivak's "Calculus", Chapter 22 Problem 26 part d

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

The problem investigates when the infinite power tower $a^{a^{a^a\ldots}}$ converges for $a > 0$ by considering the convergence of the sequence $b_{n+1} = a^{b_n}$ and calls the limit when it exists $b$.

Part c asks us to show using problem 25 that if $b$ exists then $e^{-1} \leq b$. Problem 25 proves the general result that in a sequence formed by iteratively applying a function $f$ with continuous first derivative (in this case $f(x) = a^x$), that $|f'(b)| \leq 1$.

However applying this to the problem just yields $|ln(a) a^b| \leq 1$. In the previous parts we have already shown that the inequality holds when $1 \leq a \leq e^{1/e}$, so I only need to apply this inequality for the case $0 < a < 1$. However this doesn't show that $b \geq e^{-1}$ or that $b \leq e$ for $0 < a < 1$.

Edit: I realise now that since $b$ is a fixed point of the recurrence, we have $|ln(a)b| \leq 1$, but I still don't see how this leads to the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out now. We just continue from
$$ |b \ln(a)| \leq 1$$
$$ |\ln(a^b)| \leq 1 $$
$$ |\ln b| \leq 1$$
$$ e^{-1} \leq b \leq e $$